# JS Функция проверки формы не работает

Tags: javascript, form, валидация

Не получается написать функцию проверяющую форму на валидность. Если все 3 поля заполнены корректно, то функция должна выводить в консоль e-mail и пароль. Создала 3 переменные а,b и с равные false и встроила их к каждому блоку по 1. Там где в условии должна быть ошибка присвоила значение false, а где все ок - true.И далее попыталась сделать проверку. Если все 3 поля = true, то в консоль должны выводиться пароль и почта. Но функция почему-то не работает.

Помогите пожалуйста понять, где я ошибаюсь?

```js
'use strict'

const emailChecker = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/iu;


const errorIsOn = document.querySelector('#error');
const preheader = document.querySelector('#preheader');
const emailField = document.querySelector('#e-mail');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const password = document.querySelector('#password');
const errorpass = document.querySelector('#errorpass');
const errorpass2 = document.querySelector('#errorpass2');
const preheaderpass = document.querySelector('#preheaderpass');
const checkbox = document.querySelector('#box');
const errorpass3 = document.querySelector('#errorpass3');

let a = false;
let b = false;
let c = false;

function isEmailValid(value) {
  return emailChecker.test(value);
}

function onInput() {
  if (isEmailValid(emailField.value)) {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'green';
    errorIsOn.style.display = 'none';
    preheader.style.color = 'black';
    a = true;
  } else {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorIsOn.style.display = 'initial';
    preheader.style.color = 'red';
    a = false;
  }
}

emailField.addEventListener('keyup', onInput);


function passValidation() {
  if (password.value.length === 0) {
    password.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass.style.display = 'initial';
    preheaderpass.style.color = 'red';
    errorpass2.style.display = 'none';
    b = false;
  } else if (password.value.length > 0 && password.value.length <= 8) {
    password.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass2.style.display = 'initial';
    preheaderpass.style.color = 'red';
    b = false;
  } else {
    password.style.borderColor = 'green';
    errorpass.style.display = 'none';
    errorpass2.style.display = 'none';
    preheaderpass.style.color = 'black';
    return (password);
    b = true;
  }
}

password.addEventListener('keyup', passValidation);


function checkboxValid() {
  if (!checkbox.checked === false) {
    checkbox.style.borderColor = 'black';
    errorpass3.style.display = 'none';
    c = true;
  } else {
    checkbox.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass3.style.display = 'initial';
    c = false;
  }
}

checkbox.addEventListener('click', checkboxValid);


function formValidation() {
  if (a === true && b === true && c === true) {
    console.log(emailField);
    console.log(password);
  } else {
    console.log('Поля не заполнены!')
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', formValidation);
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1440px;
  max-height: 769px;
  background-color: #1B2473;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .body {
    max-width: 768px;
  }
}

.form {
  width: 600px;
  height: 412px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 82px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .form {
    width: 728px;
    height: 697px;
  }
}

.form__preheader {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__preheader {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.form__header {
  width: 115px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__header {
    width: 138px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

.form__field {
  width: 509px;
  height: 49px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__field {
    width: 638px;
    height: 49px;
  }
}

.form__error {
  display: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #CB2424;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.form__star {
  width: 7px;
  height: 12px;
  color: #787878;
}

.form__pc {
  width: 638px;
  height: fir-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.form__box {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__box {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
}

.form__checkbox {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.form__text {
  width: 278px;
  height: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__text {
    width: 358px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.form__send {
  width: 180px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #1A226B;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__send {
    width: 220px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../module_two_javascript/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../module_two_javascript/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form class="form" id='form'>

    <h1 class="form__header">Вход</h1>
    <p class="form__preheader" id='preheader'>E-mail</p>
    <input class="form__field" type="text" id="e-mail" placeholder="Введите e-mail">
    <p class="form__error" id='error'>Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
    <p class="form__preheader" id='preheaderpass'>Пароль</p>
    <input class="form__field" type="text" id="password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
    <p class="form__error" id='errorpass'>Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
    <p class="form__error" id='errorpass2'>Пароль должен содержать как минимум 8 символов</p>

    <div class="form__pc">
      <div class=f orm__checkbox>
        <input class="form__box" type="checkbox" id="box" value='check'>
        <label for="box" class="form__text">Я согласен получать обновления на почту
        </label>
      </div>
      <p class="form__error" id='errorpass3'>Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
    </div>

    <button class="form__send" id='btn' type="submit">
            Войти
    </button>
    <script src="..."></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решила вопрос так:

JS:

```
function formValidation(evt) { 

  if (a === true && b === true && c === true) {

    evt.preventDefault();  // добавила отмену события по умолчанию и только затем вывела в консоль нужные мне значения полей.

    console.log(emailField.value);
    console.log(password.value);
  } 
}


btn.addEventListener('click', formValidation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Присвоение b стояло после return, соответственно, не выполнялось.

```js
'use strict'

const emailChecker = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/iu;


const errorIsOn = document.querySelector('#error');
const preheader = document.querySelector('#preheader');
const emailField = document.querySelector('#e-mail');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const password = document.querySelector('#password');
const errorpass = document.querySelector('#errorpass');
const errorpass2 = document.querySelector('#errorpass2');
const preheaderpass = document.querySelector('#preheaderpass');
const checkbox = document.querySelector('#box');
const errorpass3 = document.querySelector('#errorpass3');

let a = false;
let b = false;
let c = false;

function isEmailValid(value) {
  return emailChecker.test(value);
}

function onInput() {
  if (isEmailValid(emailField.value)) {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'green';
    errorIsOn.style.display = 'none';
    preheader.style.color = 'black';
    a = true;
  } else {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorIsOn.style.display = 'initial';
    preheader.style.color = 'red';
    a = false;
  }
}

emailField.addEventListener('change', onInput);


function passValidation() {
  if (password.value.length === 0) {
    password.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass.style.display = 'initial';
    preheaderpass.style.color = 'red';
    errorpass2.style.display = 'none';
    b = false;
  } else if (password.value.length > 0 && password.value.length <= 8) {
    password.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass2.style.display = 'initial';
    preheaderpass.style.color = 'red';
    b = false;
  } else {
    password.style.borderColor = 'green';
    errorpass.style.display = 'none';
    errorpass2.style.display = 'none';
    preheaderpass.style.color = 'black';
    b = true; // стояло ПОСЛЕ return
    return (password);

  }
}

password.addEventListener('change', passValidation);


function checkboxValid() {
  if (!checkbox.checked === false) {
    checkbox.style.borderColor = 'black';
    errorpass3.style.display = 'none';
    c = true;
  } else {
    checkbox.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass3.style.display = 'initial';
    c = false;
  }
}

checkbox.addEventListener('click', checkboxValid);


function formValidation() {
  if (a === true && b === true && c === true) {
    console.log(emailField.value);
    console.log(password.value);
  } else {
    console.log('Поля не заполнены!')
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', formValidation);
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1440px;
  max-height: 769px;
  background-color: #1B2473;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .body {
    max-width: 768px;
  }
}

.form {
  width: 600px;
  height: 412px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 82px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .form {
    width: 728px;
    height: 697px;
  }
}

.form__preheader {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__preheader {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.form__header {
  width: 115px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__header {
    width: 138px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

.form__field {
  width: 509px;
  height: 49px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__field {
    width: 638px;
    height: 49px;
  }
}

.form__error {
  display: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #CB2424;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.form__star {
  width: 7px;
  height: 12px;
  color: #787878;
}

.form__pc {
  width: 638px;
  height: fir-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.form__box {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__box {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
}

.form__checkbox {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.form__text {
  width: 278px;
  height: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__text {
    width: 358px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.form__send {
  width: 180px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #1A226B;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__send {
    width: 220px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../module_two_javascript/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../module_two_javascript/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form class="form" id='form'>

    <h1 class="form__header">Вход</h1>
    <p class="form__preheader" id='preheader'>E-mail</p>
    <input class="form__field" type="text" id="e-mail" placeholder="Введите e-mail">
    <p class="form__error" id='error'>Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
    <p class="form__preheader" id='preheaderpass'>Пароль</p>
    <input class="form__field" type="text" id="password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
    <p class="form__error" id='errorpass'>Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
    <p class="form__error" id='errorpass2'>Пароль должен содержать как минимум 8 символов</p>

    <div class="form__pc">
      <div class=f orm__checkbox>
        <input class="form__box" type="checkbox" id="box" value='check'>
        <label for="box" class="form__text">Я согласен получать обновления на почту
        </label>
      </div>
      <p class="form__error" id='errorpass3'>Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
    </div>

    <button class="form__send" id='btn' type="submit">
            Войти
    </button>
    <script src="..."></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: да, верно... но функция все равно не работает как надо. у меня в любом случае выдает сообщение, что поля не заполнены

Comment: При запуске кода в моем ответе выдает такое сообщение? Я вижу, что выводятся инпуты на email и пароль, а это альтернативная ветка.

Comment: да, я вроде скопировала и запустила код с Вашими правками, но не получилось получить e-mail  и почту. Сейчас еще разок попробую запустить.

Comment: Поля заполняли вручную или подставлялись запомненные значения? Во втором случае, действительно, рамка инпута остается красной и выводится сообщение поля не заполнены.

Comment: нет, заполняю вручную и выдает всегда сообщение, что поля не заполнены

Comment: Плюс ко всему надо чтобы выводились не инпуты в консоль, а именно введенные пароль и почта (если удовлетворены все 3 условиях валидная почта, валиден пароль (не менее 8 символов) и поставлена галочка  согласия).

Comment: Если задан вывод переменных, содержащих инпуты, не стоит удивляться, что выводятся инпуты, а не значения. :) Это я поправил. С сообщением о незаполненных полях не совсем понятно. По крайней мере здесь в песочнице все нормально работает. Я сейчас перенастроил слушатель на изменение поля вместо отпускания клавиши. Возможно, это проблему решит.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за помощь! В итоге я сделала немного иначе, но Вы давали очень дельные советы, которые я обязательно возьму на вооружение!